# Powershell reporting wrong info for Protected OU

Tags: powershell, organizational-unit

`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -Properties ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion | where {$_.ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion -eq $false} | ft DistinguishedName,ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion`

Shows "False" for OU's that are indeed protected.

Is this a bug? Or is there a more proper way to perform this query?

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.953
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.953
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Possibly, does The Domain Controller's (2008R2) Framework have to be upgraded?  It is an older PS version:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.36373
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: Is replication working properly?

Comment: `dcdiag /test:replications`  passed tests

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties again.

- In "Active Directory Users and Computers", click on View and then click on Advanced Featured (make sure that is check as showed):
  [image: Checked Advanced Features in AD]

---

- After running your lines (it imported the AD module and then ran the script). with this results (DC 2012R2 std):

[image: Case False]

---

- So I went into the "domain Controllers" OU/Right click then properties)
  [image: DC OU]

---

- Now go into the Object Tab and check if the checkbox for "Protect Object from accidental deletion" is checked or not .(if it's selected won't appears into your PowerShell Query, if it's not will appear).

[image]

And one last thing, since FT change the objects to be presented in screen it changes the objects. So I would change "ft" for "select" so it preserves the objects

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -Properties ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion | where {$_.ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion -eq $false} | Select DistinguishedName,ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion
```

Comment: select vs ft = no change. https://postimg.org/gallery/252i8grh2/ Logically it should work as described; however, the items ARE protected, but powershell reports the opposite.

Comment: Try to Re-Use a object using ft, and then try to use it as "select" and let me know which one worked

Comment: technically what i'm doing is piping to Set-ADOrganizationalUnit  -ProtectFromAccidentalDeletion:$true, but when i re-run to find unprotected OU's, they still show up in the list (falsely).  verbatim from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723677(v=ws.10).aspx and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1e20fcab-a09e-45b5-8860-cb2523432191/powershell-to-enable-protect-from-accidental-deletion-on-all-ous?forum=winserverpowershell .. They DO get set, but still report not set.

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to uncheck/apply then re-check/apply via GUI; afterward, the powershell output was valid.